# Redirect internal to path, if resource doesn't exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am trying to redirect internally to another location, so the user won't see the "script" location / uri, if an image does not exists:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources/img/tires [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^resources/img/tires/(.*)$ reifen/imagematch/$1 [L]
```

For example if i request an image:

`http://domain.tld/resources/img/tires/manufacturer/image.jpg` -> Image exists, directly serve the image.

And if i request:

`http://domain.tld/resources/img/tires/manufacturerX/image2.jpg` -> Image does not exist, 
call the script which is located at `http://domain.tld/reifen/imagematch/{manufacturerX/image2.jpg}`

What do i have to modify in my rewrite rules, so that the shown example will work correctly?

Best regards and thanks!

Comment: Your rule is working as is for me.

Make sure you're using RewriteEngine On before the RewriteCond statement.

Comment: The rewrite module is turned on, but the rule won't work...

Comment: I am using codeigniter and try to access an controller with my method. Maybe thats the problem

UPDATE:
Yup, thats the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^resources/img/tires/(.+)$ /reifen/imagematch/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This rule also doesn't work. It always tries to find the scriptpath inside "resources" and not relative to the root path.

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess file?