# nginx - Redirect internal to path, if resource doesn't exists

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

once i asked, if someone can check a rule for apache2: [Redirect internal to path, if resource doesn't exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300461/redirect-internal-to-path-if-resource-doesnt-exists)

But now i need it for nginx.
Can someone help me to rewrite the rule for nginx?

I tried some converters, but they didn't help me :(

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources/img/tires [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^resources/img/tires/(.*)$ reifen/imagematch/$1 [L]
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: How do you call the script that will serve image?

Comment: I'm calling it via domain.tld/reifen/imagematch/$var as you can see in my other question

Comment: I mean what is relevant part in your nginx config? And it's better to show full nginx config.